# Imgur Api is over capacity:

Tags: reactjs, imgur

Imgur Api is over capacity:

{"data":{"error":"Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."},"success":false,"status":403}

my code:

```
import qs from 'qs';
import axios from 'axios';
const CLIENT_ID = 'a45f2e351b43b50';
const ROOT_URL = 'https://api.imgur.com';

export default {
    login() {
        const querystring = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            response_type: 'token'
        };
        location.assign(`${ROOT_URL}/oauth2/authorize?${qs.stringify(querystring)}`);
    },
    fetchImages(token) {
        return axios
            .get(`${ROOT_URL}/3/account/me/images`, {
                headers: {  
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
    }
};
```

I need support with my code and imgur api, I don't get why my qustion is getting disapproval!!!?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. What is the question you have?

Comment: What is unclear from the response? If Imgur isn't accepting requests there's not much we can do about it.

Comment: Yea I know, but imgur support says to post the problems at stackoverflow with the imgur tag to get support.

Answer (score 1):

Status 403 means the server understands your request, but refuses it. Judging from the message attached to it, The API is just bogged down with requests and needs time to become operational again. Just wait a little while and try your code again.

Comment: Yes, it is 403 in the page, but the console response is 429.
Anyway, how can I make a request after this response is received?
Should I use a "setInterval"? or a catch phrase? 

And the thing is when I enter the location manually, it works fine with google; But it doesn't make it with my app location assigning!!